# stuck with writing facebook authentication in django

Tags: django, facebook, authentication

This is the code that i've come up with inspired from django RemoteUserBackend its not yet complete, I am not sure where in normal backends or in remoteuserbackend for instance where exactly the authenticate method called from ? Sorry I am new to django and the userlog in process seems to work like *magic*

```
from django.contrib import ModelBackend      
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Permission

def facebook_login_required(orig_view):
    def wrapper(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            redirect_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=email,read_stream'%(SETTINGS.FB_APPID,request.getlocation)
            HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            # user is logged in, its safe to process the view
            return orig_view
    return wrapper

class FacebookAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self,userid):
        """
        The ``userid`` passed here is considered trusted.This method
        simply returns the ``User`` objects with the given id, else
        it creates a new user with the this ``userid`` if the it does
        not existz
        """
        if not userid:
            user = User(userid=userid)
            user.save()
        user = None
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(userid=userid)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return user

    def get_user(self,userid):
        try:
            User.objects.get(userid=userid)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: why not use something like django social auth? https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth ;)

Comment: +1 for `django-social-auth`. It's very easy to set up, integrates with the existing `django.contrib.auth` and is very well documented, with an active forum on Convore

Comment: I want to do this on my own for the purpose of learning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always have a look at the source code and figure out how things work and with yours don't

https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/backends/facebook.py